# Agregar módulos a un ambiente de python ya creado utilizando conda

Tags: python, packages, virtualenv

Estoy incursionando en Python y estoy un poco confundido con el uso de los entornos virtuales.

He creado uno utilizando el comando

```
conda create --name pythonEnv2 python=3 matplotlib pillow
```

Pero ahora tengo la siguiente duda: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para agregar otros módulos, por ejemplo *h5py* a ese mismo ambiente virtual? Todas las ayudas y tutoriales que encontré explican como crear un ambiente desde cero, pero no pude encontrar cómo agregar o eliminar paquetes a uno ya creado.

Lo intenté con

```
conda activate pythonEnv2
conda install h5py
```

Pero de ese modo me pide descargar el paquete nuevamente, lo que no tiene ningún sentido pues ya lo descargué con Anaconda.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes activar el entorno virtual:

```
source activate nombre_de_tu_entorno_virtual
```

Luego, instalas el paquete que deseas:

```
pip install nombre_del_paquete
```

ó mejor:

```
conda install nombre_del_paquete
```

Si ya descargaste el paquete, entonces:

```
conda install ruta_en_donde_se_encuentra_el_paquete_junto_con_el_nombre_del_paquete_y_su_extensión
```